# How to invoke Jemalloc.dll into application running on windows 7 32-bit

Tags: java, c++, jemalloc

I want to use jemalloc for memory profiling of DLLs.

I am using jemalloc 4.3.0. I build it in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Now how can `jemalloc.dll` be used in the application?

The application is in Java and it uses native code written in C++. My OS is Windows 7, 32-bit.

Comment: Is your C++ code using `new` or `std::allocator` or `std::make_shared` ? (I.e. C++ functions). In that case, it would be trivial - just override `::operator new` to call `jemalloc`. The problem is that you can't override `malloc`.

Comment: @MSalters : C++ code is using new and malloc. so is it that I have to manually change the malloc to jemalloc ? Is there any way that all the mallocs being replaced to jemalloc by just including the dll. As i have seen post that in unix we just have to Use the LD_PRELOAD environment variable to inject jemalloc into the application at run time. https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Getting-Started